# How to immediately trigger notification actions for problem alerts suppressed by Zabbix during maintenance

Tags: zabbix

How to immediately trigger notification actions for problem alerts suppressed by Zabbix during maintenance, for those that have not yet been restored after maintenance ends?
Version: Zabbix 5.0.13
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd8mM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llYz5.png)
expect Actions of sending mail

Comment: screenshots are cropped, that looks like a Warning problem, and the action is for Average or more